# How can I get the data based on the node ID in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm trying to figure out how to do some things in Memgraph. I'd like to fetch data based on a node ID. How can I get something like `(:label {nodeid: __})`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to retrieve a node labeled Person with the internal id 578:

`MATCH (p:Person) WHERE id(p)=578 RETURN p`;